# how to set the contents of a textarea in HTML by passing a String from a servlet to it

Tags: html, forms, servlets, textarea

I am trying to pass the value of a string to a textarea so it would be visible in the textarea. Looks like there is no attribute like 'value' in textarea.

Comment: You want to set the value using JavaScript or on the server-side? If server-side just use `<textarea>this is content</textarea>`

Comment: btw this has nothing to do with servlets

Comment: @home I asked a friend and gave the same solution and it was right

Answer (score 4):

The 'textarea' tag does have attribute 'value', see: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_textarea.asp

In case you want to put the content in textarea to be a string gotten from server, you must call to the server to get the value by AJAX from your JavaScript code. A little guide: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp

There are other advanced methods to do this with Java Applet, ActiveX,... but this is for advanced purposes only.

Answer (score 3):

The attribute on text area to set the content is `textarea.innerText` for IE and `textarea.textContent` for firefox.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following code and it worked. I just entered the string within the textarea tags as follows: String value

```
<% String textAreaValue = session.getAttribute("textArea"); %>

<textarea rows = "4" cols = "20" name = "area" id = "area"><% if(condition) { %>
<%=textAreaValue %><%}%> </textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also set its contents using JQuery by:

```
$("#id_of_textarea").val("here is your message");
```

or using javascript by:

```
document.getElementById("id_of_textarea").value = "here is your message";
```